Which scripture narrates Krishna's journey to Kailasa to pray to Lord Shiva for the birth of Pradyumna?
According to the Puranic Encyclopedia by Vettam Mani, the following account is mentioned regarding the birth of Pradyumna:

While Śrī Kṛṣṇa was living as the chief of Dvārakā his first wife
Rukmiṇī was yearning for a child. Kṛṣṇa was deeply moved by the grief
of Rukmiṇī and he flew on the back of Garuḍa to Kailāsa to obtain a
boon for the birth of a child for her. On the way he alighted in the
āśrama of Naranārāyaṇas and after obtaining the blessings of the sages
there, went to Kailāsa and bowed before Śiva and explained to him the
purpose of his visit. Śiva blessed him and said that Kāmadeva who was
burnt to death by the fire of his third eye would take birth again as
the son of Rukmiṇī. Kṛṣṇa returned to Dvārakā well-pleased. Rukmiṇī
became pregnant and gave birth to Pradyumna, a rebirth of Kāmadeva.

I would like to know which scripture or Purana contains this story in detail.
